# Is it possible to bundle a precomposed binary in VsCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I'm in the process or porting a command line app which makes heavy use of ZeroMQ for scheduling to a VsCode extension

I know that it's possible to bundle binaries in an electron app but what about binaries in VsCode extension?

I wish to use the compiled binaries for

https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/

Comment: Yes, it is. Just place the binary into the extension directory and let vsce do the rest.

Comment: Hmm, right. Thanks @Wosi

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, just include the binary in the extension directory when running `vsce publish`.